# Evenly Divide horizontal space between elements on Mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I generate a list of buttons dynamically. And the number of items is different between routes.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("keysController", function keysController() {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.keys = ["id", "destination", "body", "state", "createdDate", "processedDate"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="keysController">

  <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap mb-0">
    <li ng-repeat="key in $ctrl.keys">
      <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn mx-1">
      {{key}}
    </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On Desktop, since there is enough space, all the items are on the same line. However, on small size screen, they are, at least, on two lines. In that case, they should take all the horizontal space.

#### Use this code, if you answer.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap mb-0">
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark mx-1">
      id
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark mx-1">
      destination
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark mx-1">
      body
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark mx-1">
      state
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark mx-1">
      createdDate
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark mx-1">
      processedDate
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Update

It seems that I have not explained the issue clearly. So, I want to explain it further.

The `ul`, `li`, and `button` should all be responsive. If the items are wrapped, it is fine. However, they should occupy all the space. For instance, if there is one item on a line, it should take all the line: its width should be equal to that of the line.  If there are two, they should take the width of that line evenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `list-unstyled`, you can use the `nav-fill` class which applies this CSS to the `nav-item`s:

```
.nav-fill .nav-item {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then use `btn-block` to make the buttons full width...

https://www.codeply.com/go/UhpH2JMtjL

Alternatively, `flex-grow-1` and `px-1` could be used on the the `li`, and then `w-100` or `btn-block` in the buttons.

---

Or, if you want to keep the same markup use CSS like this...

```css
.list-unstyled > li {
flex:1 1 auto;
padding:0 1px;
}
.list-unstyled li .btn {
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap mb-0">
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark">
      id
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark">
      destination
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark">
      body
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark">
      state
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark">
      createdDate
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark">
      processedDate
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: `mx-1` was removed from the btn's.

Comment: Thanks. It works. However,  I do not want to use the `nav nav-fill` because it is not for navigation. You can use Bootstrap helper class Instead of the `CSS` code.

Comment: Yeah you can do that too.

Comment: I found that `col` and `flex-grow-1` both work. Which one do you think I should use?

Comment: I think `flex-grow-1`, since `col` is meant to be inside `row`.

Answer (score 0):

After half an hour, I found three different solutions using `Bootstrap` only.

1. Az `ZimSystem` has said, instead of using `list-unstyled`, use the `nav` and `nav-fill` classes. And then, use `btn-block` on buttons.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-fill d-flex flex-wrap mb-0">
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      id
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      destination
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      body
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      state
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      createdDate
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      processedDate
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

2. Use `flex-grow-1` on items and `btn-block` on buttons.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap mb-0">
  <li class="flex-grow-1 mx-1 mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      id
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-grow-1 mx-1 mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      destination
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-grow-1 mx-1 mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      body
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-grow-1 mx-1 mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      state
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-grow-1 mx-1 mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      createdDate
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-grow-1 mx-1 mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      processedDate
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

3. Use `col` on items and `btn-block` on buttons.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap mb-0">
  <li class="col mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      id
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="col mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      destination
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="col mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      body
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="col mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      state
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="col mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      createdDate
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="col mb-1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      processedDate
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```